# Regex for US Federal Tax ID (EIN)

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, validation-rule, regular-expressions

In the pattern attribute of an input tag, I am using the following regular expression for validation of the US Federal Tax ID field.

```
pattern="^[1-9][0-9]{8}$"
```

But this regex allows 111111111, 222222222 (all same digits) type of entries. This type of entry should not be allowed. Please help with the correct regex.

Comment: This strikes me as something that can't be done with regex. Your current regex also shouldn't be matching either of your examples, or any other EIN, because it doesn't account for the `-`.

Comment: In addition to what Derek said, your regex does not disallow repeating digits. Your regex is just saying that it has to be 9 digits long and not start with a zero.  Try something like https://regexr.com/ to test your patterns.

Comment: @Moonpie The "disallow repeating digits" is the part that can't be done with regex, at least not easily/reliably/succinctly. That's a rule that's more in line with a "context free" language than a "regular" language (regex works on "regular" languages).

Comment: @DerekF FYI, you can use capture groups to detect repeating values, such as: `^(\d)\1{2}-?\1{2}-?\1{4}$` or `^(\d)\1{8}$`

Answer (score 4):

## EIN

The EIN has the origin code (a two-character prefix) plus a seven-digit number. It is conceptually possible for certain numbers to exist:

- 11-1111111
- 22-2222222
- 33-3333333
- 44-4444444
- 55-5555555
- 66-6666666
- 77-7777777
- 88-8888888
- 99-9999999

There's no mention that these numbers are impossible, though obviously the higher numbered ones would probably take a very long time to reach, if ever.

An appropriate pattern for this, then, would be:

```
^(01|02|03|04|05|06|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|30|32|33|34|35|36|37|38|39|40|41|42|43|44|45|46|46|47|48|50|51|52|53|54|55|56|57|58|59|60|61|62|63|64|65|66|67|68|71|72|73|74|75|76|77|80|81|82|83|84|85|85|86|86|87|87|88|88|90|91|92|92|93|94|95|98|99|)-\d{7}$
```

This includes [all known prefixes](https://www.irs.gov/businesses/small-businesses-self-employed/how-eins-are-assigned-and-valid-ein-prefixes) today, including the reserved 47, which should cover every valid number.

## SSN

Since the SSA introduced [SSN Randomization](https://www.ssa.gov/employer/randomization.html) more than a decade ago, it is entirely possible that the following numbers exist and are valid, or will exist in the future:

- 111-11-1111
- 222-22-2222
- 333-33-3333
- 444-44-4444
- 555-55-5555
- 777-77-7777
- 888-88-8888

The number is broken into three parts, the Area, Group, and Serial numbers. The following rules apply:

- Area may be any value except 000, 666, 900-999.
- Group may be any value except 00.
- Serial may be any value except 0000.

If you really wanted a regex for this, it would look like:

```
^(?!000|666|9\d{2})\d{3}-?(?!00)\d{2}-?(?!0000)\d{4}$
```

If you want to be able to parse them later for some reason, you can add capture groups:

```
^(?!000|666|9\d{2})(\d{3})-?(?!00)(\d{2})-?(?!0000)(\d{4})$
```

Edit: As a practical matter, I realized if I were using this, I'd want to make sure they use either 2 dashes or none, which we can fix with a backreference:

```
^(?!000|666|9\d{2})\d{3}(-?)(?!00)\d{2}\1(?!0000)\d{4}$
```

Or with the other capture groups:

```
^(?!000|666|9\d{2})(\d{3})(-?)(?!00)(\d{2})\2(?!0000)(\d{4})$
```

Comment: This is awesome, but it seems that the OP is validating EINs (https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p1635.pdf) rather than SSNs. From linked doc: *"An Employer Identification Number (EIN) is a nine-digit number that IRS assigns
in the following format: XX-XXXXXXX."*

Comment: Even better info regarding the format: https://www.irs.gov/businesses/small-businesses-self-employed/how-eins-are-assigned-and-valid-ein-prefixes. The prefix has significance, but there is no explicit statement on this linked page that the prefix is limited to certain numbers. However, the table on the page does not include: 07, 08, 09, 17, 18, 19, 28, 29, 49, 69, 70, 78, 79, 89, 96 or 97.

Comment: @Moonpie Yeah, I read "Federal Tax ID" and just checked out. The IRS actually has a list of all possible prefixes [here](https://www.irs.gov/businesses/small-businesses-self-employed/how-eins-are-assigned-and-valid-ein-prefixes) and where they originate from. I can actually edit that in, but I'll leave the SSN version for anyone who might need it.

Comment: ^(\d)(?!\1+$)\d{7}\d{1}$ This regex will not allow same digits but i also don't want the starting number to allow zero how to make the change

Comment: @RajivSingh The starting number of 0 is a *potentially valid* EIN. In fact, I've worked for a number of employers that had 01 or 03 as EINs, thinking about it. I've provided you with a perfectly usable EIN validation scheme.